# What is the Wordpress Add Video icon supposed to do?

Tags: video, embedding, wordpress

I love Wordpress, and for the most part it is self-explanitory and easy to use.

However, the "Add Video" icon on the edit post page seems to be almost completely useless.

[Add Video Button http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/9383/badaddvideo.jpg](http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/9383/badaddvideo.jpg)

Here's what I did:

- Press the "Add Video" button
- Uploaded a video file from my local machine called ballon.mpg
- Pressed the "Insert into post" button

The result is a Hyperlink called "balloon" to the URL of the video file.  Not what I expected.

Is this the functionality that is supposed to happen?

I administer a Wordpress MU blog, and my users are confused about why the icon is there if it doesn't automatically embed local video.

Is there a way for me to hide that icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is the correct functionality. I'm not sure of a way to hide the button, but you could certainly enhance it's behavior using the [JW Player Plugin for Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/). When you click the 'Add Video' button, you'll be presented with additional options, including the ability to insert a video player directly into the post, like so:

[image]

This will generate a quick code, which will then render a player directly in the post.

Best,

Zach

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you explain why it's more like what you'd expect?

Comment: I have just tested out the JW Player Plugin and it makes Wordpress behave exactly as I would expect it to in the first place.  I definitely recommend the plugin ( I'm removing my comment about the other plugin as I now wish I had found the JW Player Plugin first ).